# What is the right way to implement addition using class in Python and avoid TypeError with missing positional argument?

Tags: python, class

```
class Add:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(a,b):
       return self.a + self.b

obj = Add(3,4)
print(obj.add())
```

Error message:

```
print(obj.add())
          ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Add.add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `def add(a,b):`, what do you think this means? in particular, what do you think it means to put `a, b` between the `()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Add:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b

obj = Add(3,4)
print(obj.add())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only take `self` as a parameter. The other values are accessed on the instance itself.

```py
def add(self):
   return self.a + self.b
```